# how to do a dictionary reverse lookup

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary of type `<string, string>` and for a particular case, I need to do a reverse lookup. So for instance suppose I have this entry `<"SomeString", "ab">` and that I pass in `"ab"` then I would like to return `"SomeString"`. 
Before I embark on a `foreach` loop over every entry in the dictionary, I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to do this reverse lookup?

Comment: With a single key->value dictionary, the foreach loop is the most efficient way to get a key from a value.

Comment: There is no build-in mechanism to get Key by Value.

Comment: LINQ on the value will be O(n).  If you want O(1) then you would need to implement two dictionaries - in the second you just reverse the key and value.

Comment: What do you want to do if your dictionary has multiple elements with the same value?

Comment: @ZombieSheep: that won't happen in this particular case.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Basically, You can use `LINQ` and get the `Key` like this, without reversing anything:

```
var key = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "ab").Key;
```

If you really want to reverse your Dictionary, you can use an extension method like this:

```
public static Dictionary<TValue, TKey> Reverse<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
{
     var dictionary = new Dictionary<TValue, TKey>();
     foreach (var entry in source)
     {
         if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(entry.Value))
             dictionary.Add(entry.Value, entry.Key);
     }
     return dictionary;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var reversedDictionary = dictionary.Reverse();
var key = reversedDictionary["ab"];
```

Note: if you have duplicate values then this method will add the *first* `Value` and ignore the others.

Comment: Arguably nicer code, but no more efficient than a `for-each`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer; I like linq 1-liners a lot, even though I know underneath it's just going to become a for-each loop.

Comment: That Reverse is O(n) - why perform a O(n) to avoid and O(n).   The way to do that is a Collection that goes both ways and add to both.

Comment: ... `Reverse` crashes on {1 => "a", 2 => "a"}.

Comment: `Reverse` is a terrible name, the method isn't reversing anything at all! `Flip` or `Swap` or `Switch` would make much more sense.

Comment: @IanKemp agreed. I googled dictionary invert to get here (and ended up using http://stackoverflow.com/a/33899013/59996)

Comment: @IanKemp invert might be a better name; but flip, swap, and even invert switch all suffer from the same problem: lack of specificity; nevertheless, "reverse" is what I searched for, because that's what I expected to find used.

Comment: All LINQ methods that return materialized collections are named `ToSomething` (`ToArray`, `ToList`, `ToDictionary`, `ToHashSet`). By materialized I mean not-deferred. So to keep up with the convention, this one could be named `ΤοReverseDictionary`.

Comment: +1 for the in-place lookup (LINQ) as it is by far the most efficient way to do this (speed, resources, etc).

Answer (score 65):

Use the Linq `ToDictionary` function:

```
var reversed = d.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);
```

You can see below that it works, as tested in Linqpad:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
d.Add(1,"one");
d.Add(2,"two");
d.Dump(); //prints it out in linq-pad
var reversed = d.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);
reversed.Dump(); //prints it out in linq-pad
```

[image: Prints]

Comment: Dump isn't a built-in method.  You should probably document what it does.

Comment: It prints stuff out in linq-pad, sort of extended Console.Write .. It's already mentioned the code is tested in linq-pad?

Comment: Maybe the problem will be if you have not unique values... like Key=3, Value="two", this will throw an exception.

Answer (score 11):

How about using the linq function ToDictionary:

```
var reversedDictionary = dictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);
```

Comment: A literally identical answer was posted a year ago.

Comment: Oh yeah. I prefer mine though.

Comment: @Servy Not seeing anything even close to identical. This gets to an answer very quickly and legibly. In that quality, it's the only answer which competes with the accepted answer; but it *could* use more background information.

Comment: Finally found [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33899013/712526) @Servy is referring to, and edited it to be more to the point.

Answer (score 2):

1) Keys are unique, values are not. For a given value you have a set of keys.

2) Lookup by key is `O(log n)`. Iterating with `foreach` or LINQ is `O(n)`.

So,
Option A: Iterate with LINQ, spend `O(n)` per request, no additional memory.
Option B: Maintain `Dictionary<ValueType, HashSet<KeyType>>`, spend `O(log n)` per request, use `O(n)` additional memory. (There are two suboptions: build this dictionary before a series of look-ups; maintain it all the time)

Comment: Dictionary lookup by key is O(1) - by hashbucket

Comment: Remarks on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx literally says "close to O(1)". I'll dig deeper and get back with my findings.

Comment: Here is the source: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary@cs/5/Dictionary@cs The code in question is at line 248. So, the speed of a look up is as good as key's hashfunction [for .Net's Dictionary<T, V>] and it's `O(n)` in worst [read: carefully crafted] case.

Comment: See line 239 private void Insert. Hint that would effect insert speed - not lookup.   Lookup would only be O(n) if every item produced the same hash - that is not worst case that is someone intentionally breaks the hash.  And you asserted 0(log n).   Where the evidence of Dictionary lookup is 0(log n)?

Comment: `O(log n)` was my assumption as it is the best timing to do look up on  an ordered set (S, <=). That was discussed in 'Introduction to Algorithms' by Cormen & others.

Comment: To be fair, I've computed hashes of all my files and for ~700k files there ~180 collisions of the hash. For 10M generated guids there were 11k collisions of the hash. Which speaks in favor on using hash functions on practice.

Comment: But this is NOT an ordered set.  The question is Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse lookup extension method for generic `Dictionary<TKey key, TValue value>` object:

"Non-Guaranteed Unique Values" extension:

```
public static TKey[] ReverseLookup<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> me, TValue value)
{
    try
    {
        if (me.ContainsValue(value))
            return me.Where(a => a.Value.Equals(value)).Select(b => b.Key).ToArray();
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

"Guaranteed Unique Values" extension:

```
public static TKey SmartReverseLookup<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> me, TValue value, TKey DefaultIfEmpty)
{
    try
    {
        if (me.ContainsValue(value))
            return me.First(a => a.Value.Equals(value)).Key;

        return DefaultIfEmpty;
    }
    catch
    {
        return DefaultIfEmpty;
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do is call it from any valid dictionary... example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> numsList = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"Test One", 1}
    {"Test Two", 2}
    {"Test Three", 3}
    {"Test Four", 3}
}

string[] foundKeys;
foundKeys = numsList.ReverseLookup(3);

Console.WriteLine(numsList.SmartReverseLookup(2, "NOT FOUND"));

Console.WriteLine("foundKeys = " + (foundKeys != null ? ("Alive [" + foundKeys.Count() + "]") : "NULL"));

Console.WriteLine(numsList.SmartReverseLookup(4, "!! UNKNOWN !!"));
```

Should yield:

```
"Test Two"
"foundKeys = Alive[2]"
"!! UNKNOWN !!"
```

Answer (score -4):

When the actual look-up direction of the dictionary (key > value) isn't of interest you can construct it in the other direction from the scratch. In addition, an extension method for IDictionary (Of TKey, TValue) is helpful, which makes it easier to capture multiple keys for one value.

#### An example

**The problem:** In a set of time units each of them could be given different names e. g., "h", "hr", "hrs", "hour", or "hours" for the time unit "hour" and I've got to find the fitting time unit for a name or abbreviation.

**My solution:** (it's VB.net, but it should be easy to convert)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class TimeUnit

    Private ReadOnly _name As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal avgSpan As TimeSpan)
        _name = name
        _AvgSpan = avgSpan
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property AvgSpan() As TimeSpan

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _name
    End Function

End Class

Public Class TimeUnits

    Private ReadOnly _items As New Dictionary(Of String, TimeUnit)(37, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) _
        From {{{"n", "min", "minute", "minutes", "minuten"},
               New TimeUnit("Minute", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))},
              {{"h", "hr", "hrs", "std", "stunde", "hour", "stunden", "hours"},
               New TimeUnit("Hour", TimeSpan.FromHours(1))},
              {{"d", "t", "day", "tag", "days", "tage"},
               New TimeUnit("Day", TimeSpan.FromDays(1))},
              {{"m", "mo", "month", "monat", "months", "monate"},
               New TimeUnit("Month", TimeSpan.FromDays(30.4375))},
              {{"q", "quarter", "quartal", "quarters", "quartale"},
               New TimeUnit("Quarter", TimeSpan.FromDays(91.3125))},
              {{"y", "yy", "yyy", "yyyy", "j", "year", "jahr", "years", "jahre"},
               New TimeUnit("Year", TimeSpan.FromDays(365.25))}}

    Public Function GetByAbbreviation(ByVal abbreviation As String) As TimeUnit
        Return _items(abbreviation)
    End Function

End Class

Public Module ExtensionMethods
    <Extension>
    Public Sub Add(Of TKey, TValue)(ByVal valItems As IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue), ByVal valKeys As IEnumerable(Of TKey), ByVal valValue As TValue)
        For Each tempKey As TKey In valKeys
            valItems.Add(tempKey, valValue)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module

Public Module Main
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim name As String = "Jahr"
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The time unit for '{0}' is {1}.", name, (New TimeUnits).GetByAbbreviation(name)))
    End Sub
End Module
```

output: The time unit for 'Jahr' is Year.