# C# - Looking for a simple way to parse a string value between two different representations (numerical and english)

Tags: c#, string, parsing, switch-statement

I'm currently developing a small helper application for something, and was wondering if there were a better way to accomplish this one thing -

I have a CSV file that I am reading into my program, and I am parsing one of the values in each row from a numerical value (always an integer, between 1 and 5) to a string value for easier representation within the program. When I save the file, I need to convert *back* from the string representation to the numerical representation. Currently, I am doing this via a switch statement but I know there must be a terser way to accomplish this.

The function I am currently using takes two arguments. One of the arguments is a string that can be either the numerical representation *or* the string representation of that value I am trying to parse, and the other value is a boolean that tells the function which way it should convert the first argument. If the boolean argument is true it converts to a numerical representation, and if false it converts to the string representation. Here is my function to parse the value:

```
string ParseRarity(string rarity, bool toNumericalStr)
{
    if (toNumericalStr)
    {
        switch (rarity)
        {
            case "Very Common":
                return "1";
            case "Common":
                return "2";
            case "Standard":
                return "3";
            case "Rare":
                return "4";
            case "Very Rare":
                return "5";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (rarity)
        {
            case "1":
                return "Very Common";
            case "2":
                return "Common";
            case "3":
                return "Standard";
            case "4":
                return "Rare";
            case "5":
                return "Very Rare";
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Any help with shortening this code would be greatly appreciated, so "thank you" in advance!

Comment: Have you ever heard of Enums?  You could create a single Enum called Rarity, spell out all your different rarities inside it and each one will have a numerical value.  Also, avoid writing methods that do two distinct things thats a sloppy thing to do

Answer (score 1):

I'll toss an answer in too, you could create a static "repository" class that contains your rarity values.  The underlining storage mechanism is a `Dictionary<int, string>`.  This will force all your rarities to have a unique key (the `int`), and it will be fast to access by that key.

```
public static class RarityRepository
{
    private static Dictionary<int, string> _values = new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {  
        { 1, "Very Common" },
        { 2, "Common" },
        { 3, "Standard" },
        { 4, "Rare" },
        { 5, "Very Rare" },
    };

    public static string GetStringValue(int input)
    { 
        string output = string.Empty;  // returns empty string if no matches are found
        _values.TryGetValue(input, out output);
        return output;
    }

    public static int GetIntValue(string input)
    {
        var result = _values.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Compare(x.Value, input, true) == 0);
        if (result.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<int,string>)))
        {
            return -1; // returns -1 if no matches are found
        }
        return result.Key;
    }
}
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dUK2Mt), thanks @Ron for finding my midnight brain code flaw!

Comment: You can save a lookup by changing your `GetStringValue` to just do a `_values.TryGetValue(input, out string returnValue);` instead.

Comment: Is that case insensitive?  I can't remember

Comment: You can set the dictionary to be case insensitive in the constructor by providing the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as the value.

Comment: I thought that only worked for the Key, not the Value?

Comment: Right, I meant to just change the `GetStringValue` method, not the value lookup. You have a `ContainsKey` call and a `_values[input]` call, which can both be consolidated to `_values.TryGetValue(...)`.

Comment: Oh I am dumb Ron, sorry.  I was thinking you were talking about the `GetIntValue()` method.  Its late and I misread.  Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I like this approach of on-the-fly values rather than objects. I think it can be greatly simplified and improved. See the accepted answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595655/how-to-do-a-dictionary-reverse-lookup

Answer (score 1):

If you want dirt simple, just write a static helper class like this one:

```
public class CodeConverter
{
    private static readonly string[] lookup = new []
    {
        "[Unknown]",
        "Very Common",
        "Common",
        "Standard",
        "Rare",
        "Very Rare"
    };

    public static string CodeToString(int code)
    {
        if (code < 0 || code > lookup.GetUpperBound(0)) code = 0;
        return lookup[code];
    }

    public static int StringToCode(string text)
    {
        int i = Array.IndexOf(lookup, text);
        return Math.Min(0,i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the Math.Min(0,i) trick, but would hate to see that in production code. Not because of me, but all the junior programmers scratching their heads. That kind of goes for both methods. :)

Comment: Why use GetUpperBounds and not Length? I would use that only to teach people VB6

Comment: Also, O(n) reverse lookup, when O(1) is entirely possible!

Comment: @AlexC. Because `code > lookup.Length` would be incorrect. I am not too worried about *O(n)* when n= 5.

Comment: I just re-visited reference sources + docs for GetUpperBounds, I stand corrected! I learned something new today! About the complexity, I was thinking a parsing util might become high traffic if someone copies the code of SO and uses it in some unintended way later. It's not paranoia if they really are out to get you :) I've seen my fair share of data structure misuse, arguably my answer has an even worse case of misuse, but will take more effort to be put together :)

Comment: Last night I was surfing SO from my mobile phone :) Thank you for the clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class that can store both values and then call on each value as needed.

```
public class Rarity
{
    public Rarity(int numValue)
    {
        NumValue = numValue;

        switch(numValue)
        {
            case 1:
                StringValue = "Very Common";
                break;
            case 2:
                StringValue = "Common";
                break;
            case 3:
                StringValue = "Standard";
                break;
            case 4:
                StringValue = "Rare";
                break;
            case 5:
                StringValue = "Very Rare";
                break;
            default:
                StringValue = "";
                break;
        }
    }
    public int NumValue { get; }
    public string StringValue { get; }
}
```

As you load your CSV values you can initialize your class object (Rarity in my example) with the int value you mentioned.

```
Rarity rarity = new Rarity(my_csv_int_value);
```

Now you can grab which ever value you need at any time.

```
rarity.NumValue //1,2,3,4,5
rarity.StringValue //Very Common, Common, etc...
```

Probably about the same amount of code, but more versatile and you don't have to keep parsing out strings.

Comment: FYI:  You can use the `[Description()]` attribute on an enum to get strings with spaces attached to an enum value

Comment: @maccettura aww you're totally right. I removed my idiotic statement from my answer.

Comment: Good idea, execution needs work! 1st it does not work as-is since NumValue is not set in constructor! Second, if I am stupid, and I am, I will write    if (Val.NumValue = 3 /* it was 2 */) things will break!

Comment: Would also be nice to initialize from string too, no?

Comment: On new thought, you could also improve the code to probably use just 5 instances of string instead of one per Rarity instance.

Comment: Good call with numValue and immutable properties. This class could be greatly improved upon I agree, but was trying to just provide an idea.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to raise awareness and help future users. We're all here to learn, right? Also, consider that 99% of SO users might just copy paste a class they seem to like without second thought! :)

Comment: Sorry, it’s hard to convey tone over the internet. I appreciated the feedback. Probably should have worded that better lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something pretty simple, but you should break it into two methods. Having one method that does two things is really bad architecture.

```
public static class RarityConverter
{
    private static List<Tuple<int, string>> Rarities = new List<Tuple<int, string>>()
    {
        new Tuple<int, string>(1, "Very Common"),
        new Tuple<int, string>(2, "Common"),
        new Tuple<int, string>(3, "Standard"),
        new Tuple<int, string>(4, "Rare"),
        new Tuple<int, string>(5, "Very Rare"),
    };

    public static string ToString(int rarity)
    {
        return Rarities.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Item1 == rarity)?.Item2;
    }

    public static int? ToInt(string rarity)
    {
        return Rarities.FirstOrDefault(t => string.Compare(t.Item2, rarity, true) == 0)?.Item1;
    }
}
```

You could also use Enum's, but that would require you to use the `DescriptionAttribute` to decorate/convert the passed in string name to the enum name.

Comment: A List of Tuple?  Is there a reason for not just using a `Dictionary<int, string>`?

Comment: @maccettura Searching through the values is slower that way, but probably wouldn't be noticed with a small list.

Comment: Any sources on it being slower?  Accessing a Dictionary by its key is very, very fast.

Comment: Yes, by the key, but the values are not stored the same way the keys are. In order to search the values, each value must be searched so keys are looked up nearly O(1), while values would be O(N). I've done the math before when needing to look up by both "key" or "value" and this is faster (for larger lists), but if just looking up by key a Dictionary would be faster.

Comment: @RonBeyer But wouldn't tuple search be O(N) for both key and value?

Comment: O(1) both ways very possible :)

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend**

enum, even with the extra decoration needs. The only other competing force for me is that data should live in data land, not in code land, so I would most probably not have these values explicitly in the code!

**I do not recommend this exact approach or that of OP, I was answering the need for terseness**

Your logic is already in string to string transformation land. Why not O(1) lookup both ways? You could have a two-way lookup/dictionary.

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{  
    { ”1”, "Very Common" },
    { “2”,  "Common" },
    { “3”, "Standard" },
    { “4,” "Rare" },
    { “5”, "Very Rare" },
    { “Very Common”, “1” }
    //etc iPhone editing sucks
};
```

You could even write out just the forward lookup half of the Dictionary and have an extension method or dedicated class ToTwoWayLookup fill in the reverse lookup part to not have to type 2x the values. (See the accepted answer for [how to do a dictionary reverse lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595655/how-to-do-a-dictionary-reverse-lookup) for method), you could also remove the ContainsKey check

Then in your function you get rid of the bool parameter and just do a lookup in this dictionary .I don’t know what the function name would be... FlipRepresentation?

**I Would probably do this**

Perhaps having a reverseLookup Dictionary separately would make more sense, so you can have two methods that have more meaningful names. Terseness is not all! Strive to make the code understandable to other humans! I would prefer reading ToNumerical(“Common”), ToNumberFromRarityName, ToRarityName(“1”) or ToRarityNameFromNumber rather than FlipRepresentation(‘1”) or ParseRarity(“1”, false);

I would probably not leave string<->string land for string<->int land like other suggest to save the call to int.Parse(val) when reading from the file.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a standard this of values, if it was me I would simplify with this (depending on requirements I would either add range checking or error handling).

```
public static class Rarities
{
    private static List<string> _rarityValues = new List<string>()
    {
        "Empty",
        "Very Common",
        "Common",
        "Standard",
        "Rare",
        "Very Rare"
    };

    public static string ToRarityString(this int rarity)
    {
        return _rarityValues[rarity];
    }

    public static int ToRairityInt(this string rarity)
    {
        return _rarityValues.IndexOf(rarity);
    }
}
```

and then you can call directly from the values:

```
   var rarityInt = 1;
   var rarityString = "Rare";

   var stringValue = rarityInt.ToRarityString();
   var intValue = rarityString.ToRairityInt();
```